# Разницу (между тем-то и тем-то) можно проверить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> Но главное – икра! Икра и невероятные, нежнейшие блюда с её участием.
>   Можно заказать дегустацию и **проверить** *(оценить?)* **разницу**
>   между осетровой, белужьей, севрюжьей и иже с ними. Вот тут же и
>   поспорить. Рекомендую.

Comment: Участие -> присутствие. "Участие" даже в фантастическом смысле невозможно без совершения действий: икра даже молча медитировать не умеет. Ну не самотдачей же на съедение она "участвует" в блюде!

Comment: Стиль такой. Воля автора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из Нацкорпуса: Проверить разницу ― 0 примеров. Разницу можно определить, ощутить, почувствовать и т.д.

Оценить разницу ― хорошее сочетание.

... это дает возможность более полно и точно **оценить разницу** между музыкой, формируемой техникой бриколажа, и музыкой, формируемой техникой композиции. [Владимир Мартынов. Конец времени композиторов (2002)]

Answer (score 2):

"Проверить" можно только *наличие или отсутствие* разницы. Саму разницу можно *заметить*,  *ощутить*, *оценить*, *определить на вкус* или - в дегустационном смысле - ***прочувствовать***.